# What do I need to use keyboard in Windows Terminal?

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, windows-terminal

**tl;dr** *Since yesterday my Windows Terminal is not accepting any key presses and I cannot write any command in it. This is the only program in my Windows 11 that ignores keyboard. What should I do to resolve this? What system service or other component must be running in order to use Windows Terminal in Windows 11*?

---

When I launched Windows Terminal in my Windows 11 Pro yesterday, it showed me a notice that some service (the *Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service* if I am not mistaken) is not running and it is needed to use Windows Terminal. I don't recall the exact service name and I cannot see this warning again because I mistakenly clicked the link in it to never show this warning again.

I opened *Services* and noticed that *Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service* is disabled. I have enabled it's automatic start and started it, but noticed no change. Windows Terminal still ignores my keyboard / key presses and does not allow me to enter anything.

What else should I run or do in order to make it operative again?

Some side questions (if you can answer them as well):

1. What *Windows Terminal* has to do with touch keyboard (*Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service*)? Why it can't use regular keyboard as each and every other piece of software in my Windows 11 and as system itself (I am trying to understand this situation, because right now for me this is a piece of nonsense)?
2. What can disable *Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service*? I have never disabled it manually and yet I found it not working and not starting during Windows 11 boot (I am trying to avoid the same situation in future)?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 0):

From several Windows Terminal Github issues:

- [Terminal not accepting keyboard input in Windows 10](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/8045)
- [No keyboard input](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4448)
- [Cannot type at all | This has not got to do with touch keyboard](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/8130#issuecomment-720575268)
  .

Some suggestions from those threads:

- Let's start with the fact that you will have to reboot after enabling the service, per the third Github comment linked above.
- Also make sure that `ctfmon.exe` is running in your task list.  Some group policies disable this.
- Check that the Input Service is enabled in the registry with:

  ```
  reg query hklm\software\microsoft\input /v InputServiceEnabled
  ```

> What Windows Terminal has to do with touch keyboard ...

From a Microsoft reply in one of the issues:

> Honestly, we don't really know. All we know is that XAML Islands (the tech stack that's powering the Terminal) *does* [require it].

And ...

> What can disable Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service?

From another comment:

> Certain "de-bloating" software (and apparently MSI Afterburner) likes to disable it or suppress it in the name of making your machine less understandable and "faster".

Is anything like that in play on your system?